# video down loader just like free make video downloader

Tags: video, downloaders

when i was using windows 7 there is an application called "free make video downloader".We can download any video through this. I would like to know is there any video downloader like this. When i search through internet i found many application to download youtube video and all. But it is not supporting to other sites like videos in facebook and all

guys pls help me to find a solution for this

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use one of the many firefox plugins.

One that you can try is... https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/?src=cb-dl-mostpopular

Comment: i tried this but not satisfying